# jqGrid move drag rows

Tags: drag-and-drop, jqgrid

I'm lookin for a way to drag a group of selected rows using jqGrid.

Answer (score 6):

Look at http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. Choose on the left tree "New in Version 3.6" and then "Drag and Drop Rows".

If you means "drag a group of selected rows" inside one jqGrid table choose "Sortable Rows" on the same demo page. If you need this feature it can be interesting to look at [jqGrid disable sortablerows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747289/jqgrid-disable-sortablerows/2775577#2775577) where I describe how one can allow only selected rows be sortable (per drag a drop)

Comment: Sorry but it don't "Sortable Rows" don't let me move a group of selected rows. i can only drag & drop one at a time.
Tell me if i'm missing on something.
I need to select (for example using shift or ctrl) a couple of rows an drag & drop.

Comment: Sorry, but you should write more exactly what you want in your question. Moreover it's good to hold the same terminology which has the control which you plan to use (jqGrid). Please update your question and add exactly what you want. Is it sorting of multiple rows inside one jqGrid? You should look at the demo page http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html to see different features of jqGrid. If you want use "multiselect" jqGrid, this grid (How I know) has no special support of rows sorting. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747289/jqgrid-disable-sortablerows/2775577#2775577 also.

Comment: @oleg I think the question is not about 'sortable' Just asking how to move more than one rows into another grid. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @kamaci: One can read in the question about the row movement and about "drag a group of selected rows". Both can interpret as movement or rows inside one grid or between two grids. jqGrid has `sortableRows` method for one case and `gridDnD` for another. It doesn't matter what wanted diego2k more as year ago because he never commented my answer. What is *your* problem? Why you decide to comment the old answer?

Comment: @Oleg cos I have the same problem and didn't want to start new question that already exist so why I asked you about your opinion.

Comment: Neither that question nor documentation explains how to drag more then one row.

Comment: @kamaci: That's your question! One can't drag more then one row in jqGrid. It's restriction of the current implementation.

Comment: I think `I'm lookin for a way to drag a group of selected rows using jqGrid.` is same with my question.

Comment: @kamaci: You can move rows but **not in one drag&drop operation**. Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235828/jqgrid-drag-and-drop-multiple-rows/3236576#3236576).

Comment: Sorry folks for not came back with some feedback the point is that i give up with this, no way to drag a group of selected rows.