# jqgrid : drag and drop multiple rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to drag and drop multiple rows using jqgrid i.e Can i drag more than one row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I know this is not possible in jqGrid. Is it supported by sortable feature of jQuery UI (see http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) which are bais for the corresponding feature in jqGrid?

Moreover both "Sortable Rows" amd "Drag and Drop Rows" features of jqGrid are currently not supported if `multiselect` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Set multiselect true and get selected row on gridDnD event of JQgrid.

`multiselect: true`

```
$("#jqGrid1").jqGrid('gridDnD', {

    connectWith: '#jqGrid2',

    beforedrop: function (ev, ui, getdata, $source, $target) {

        var myGrid = $('#jqGrid1');
        var i, selRowIds = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"), n, rowData;
        for (i = 0, n = selRowIds.length; i < n; i++) {
            rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowIds[i]);
        }

    },
    ondrop: function (ev, ui, getdata) {
        //CalculateItemTotal();
    }
});
```