# Combining tableToGrid and gridDnd in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm creating two grids with the `tableToGrid` method in jqGrid. Now I'd like the rows to be drag and drop-able between these two grids. Simply adding `'gridDnD' : true` in the options does not work. How is it done?

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
tableToGrid("#table1", { gridDnD: {connectWith: "#table2" } });
tableToGrid("#table2", { gridDnD: {connectWith: "#table2" } });
}
</script>

<table id="table1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Col 1</th>
<th>Col 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Val 1</td>
<td>Val 2</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="table2">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Col 1</th>
<th>Col 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819384/jqgrid-move-drag-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gridDnD](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#drag_and_drop_rows_between_grids) is a method of jqGrid and not an option which you can use in `tableToGrid` directly. So you have to rewrite the code to something like the following:

```
tableToGrid("#table1");
tableToGrid("#table2");
$("#table1").jqGrid('gridDnD', {connectWith: "#table2"});
$("#table2").jqGrid('gridDnD', {connectWith: "#table1"});
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tableToGridWithgridDnD.htm).

**UPDATED**: I analysed the problem with *coping* of rows during drag&drop instead of *moving*. The problem seems be a compatibility problem of jqGrid with jQuery UI starting with Version 1.8.13. How you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tableToGridWithgridDnD1.htm) which uses jQuery UI 1.8.12 the code work correctly.

I found out that the lines of [grid.jqueryui.js code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.jqueryui.js#L372-L373) (the lines 11078-11079 of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`)

```
var ids = $(ui.helper).attr("id");
$($t).jqGrid('delRowData',ids );
```

are the source of the problem. The `ui.helper[0]` contains the dropped row **with empty id** starting with jQuery UI 1.8.13.

If you would change the code to

```
var id = this.id;
$($t).jqGrid('delRowData',id);
```

the code will work in both new jQuery UI (tested with 1.8.16) and in the old one (1.8.12). See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tableToGridWithgridDnD2.htm).

I have currently no time for more exact analyse of changes between jQuery UI 1.8.12 and 1.8.13. Probably there are a bug in jQuery UI. Nevertheless I will post my suggestion described above as the bugfix in the [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/). I think it will be good to have jqGrid code which has less compatibility problems with different versions of jQuery UI.

Comment: Aha, thank you. However, there is some wierd behaviour. In your demo, dragging a row copies it. Why is that?

Comment: @carlpett: See UPDATED part of my answer.

Comment: @carlpett: You are welcome! I posted my suggestions [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/drang-and-drop-not-working-since-jqueryui1-8-13/#p24910), so I hope that Tony (the developer of jqGrid) will include the fixes in the code of jqGrid.