# Jqgrid Drag and Drop is not working in tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to reorder my rows in jqgrid. I achieved this functionality using this example

click [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortableRows.htm), I have checked that sample in tablet PC,it is not working in following browsers like IE,Safari,Chrome browsers,but works in FF.

Do we have any general fix for this?

Comment: I tried just now the old demo created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2775577/315935) and it works like expected in IE and Chrome: the rows which have "not sortable" comment can't be resorted (it's the main goal of the demo: to show how to protect some rows to be resorted). All works like expected. So you should describe more exactly the problem which you have.

Comment: drag and drop not working in tablet view browsers..

Comment: Hahhh. You should describe exactly the problem and not only in comment. If you write about IE on tablet then you mean probably Windows on tablet PC. Is it so? You should think that the goal of stackoverflow is not helping the person who ask the question (you in the case), but collecting *common* questions and the answers on the question. One want to have the knowledge database. So you should always think about other readers. You can click on "edit" link below of the question and modify the text making it *helpful for other readers* who could have the same problem.

Comment: @Oleg Question was updated,kindly help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the demo which you reference many year ago for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2775577/315935). One can't expect that old versions of jQuery, jQuery UI and jqGrid will work forever.

If one just replace jQuery, jQuery UI to the current one and to use jqGrid 4.6 then the demo will better work, but it will still not work in Chrome. It's well known problems with jQuery UI. The plugin [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) is written exactly for the case.

You can verify that [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortableRows_.htm) which uses jqGrid 4.6 works already perfectly in Chrome, but not in IE. jQuery UI already works in IE on tablet PC, but `sortableRows` works on Chrome and Firefox, but it have problem in IE. Moreover one can see that the form editing dialogs can't be moved on tablet PCs (with exception of Firefox).

[**The next demo**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortableRows_free.htm) uses [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's the fork of jqGrid which I develop after Tony have changed the licence agreement of jqGrid and started [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) which is not more free. I implemented many new features in free jqGrid. I rewrote [jqDnR module](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jqdnr.js) used in jqGrid for drag&drop already for the first free jqGrid release 4.8. Free jqGrid 4.9 will be soon published.

Thus I would recommend you just use jQuery UI Touch Punch and free jqGrid to solve the described problems.

Comment: Oleg : thanks.i reffered your examples and done with the help of Jquery UI Touch Punch..thanks alot